# Widget (Slide countdown clock) doesn't update on setState

Tags: flutter

I'm fairly new to Flutter, so there might be a very simple answer to this question, and in that case I apologize.

I'm trying to create a countdown timer to a certain time in the future.
Everything works great except the timer doesn't run when the app is closed. So I tried to solve it with didChangeAppLifeCycle and check for when the app resumes and update the duration. This also works, when the app resumes, the correct duration gets printed.

But the Slide Countdown clock widget does not update to the correct duration. Even though the print message in the build method prints the correct duration. The duration shown on the screen is still the old one.

I can't figure out why the Slide countdown clock widget doesn't update when I setState. Cause the widget should rebuild with the new duration, right?

This is the package I'm using for the countdown timer: https://pub.dev/packages/slide_countdown_clock

```
class CountdownTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountdownTimerState createState() => _CountdownTimerState();
}

class _CountdownTimerState extends State<CountdownTimer> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  double countdownTime;
  Duration _duration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final launch = context.read<LaunchProvider>().upcomingLaunches[0];
      countdownTime = launch.dateUnix - DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000;
      setState(() {
        _duration = Duration(days: 1); //Duration set to days 1 on initState for testing purposes
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      //I want to update the timer when app is resumed
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
        print('App Resumed');
        final launch = context.read<LaunchProvider>().upcomingLaunches[0];
        countdownTime = launch.dateUnix - DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000;
        setState(() {
          _duration = Duration(seconds: countdownTime.round());
          //Changing this doesn't update the countdown timer  <------
          print('App life cycle resume duration $_duration}');
        });
      }
    });
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Build run with duration $_duration');
    //This prints correct duration when app life cycle resumes. But countdown timer doesn't update.
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 5),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 220,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('DD', style: TextStyle(color: colorGrey)),
                Text('HH', style: TextStyle(color: colorGrey)),
                Text('MM', style: TextStyle(color: colorGrey)),
                Text('SS', style: TextStyle(color: colorGrey)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SlideCountdownClock(
            duration: _duration,
            slideDirection: SlideDirection.Down,
            separator: ':',
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
              color: colorWhite,
              letterSpacing: 2,
            ),
            shouldShowDays: true,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? I tried runing a sample counter and resumed it seems to be getting updated

Comment: No, there are no errors. What I want to happen is that the countdown that starts with the app (24 hours) should update to the duration that I set in the didChangeAppLifecycleState method. I calculate that duration by taking a unixdate from Provider and subtracting the current DateTime.

What happens now is the 24 hour countdown starts, and I press the home button and then I start the app again, and the 24 hour countdown is still there, instead of the updated countdown that I calculate in the didChangeAppLifecycleState method.

Comment: can you try this piece of code I just modified your code since there were lot of unknown variables https://gist.github.com/maheshmnj/bd25ce561b06e61652910bbcafb35ba9

Comment: Hey, that code didn't do what I'm after. I wanted a countdown from the current time to a specific time in the future. It's basically a countdown for the next SpaceX launch.

I did solve it myself by using another countdown package that does update the countdown like I want. It doesn't have the nice animation, but it works.

I used flutter_countdown_timer instead. 

I really appreciate you trying to help :)